# Python Dataframe column value updates in for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset on which I need to do entity resolution. Hence in this dataset some records have links some records have address. I need to build a logic for it to identify each record and put the acronym as a unique identifier.

### Example  Dataset

```
ID   LINK    acronym    address

1   google      NAN        a

2   google      NAN        a

3   NAN         NAN        a

4   google      NAN        b

5   google      NAN        b

6   NAN         NAN        b
```

### Output

```
 ID   LINK     acronym       address

    1   google      google        a

    2   google      google        a

    3   NAN         google        a

    4   google      google        b

    5   google      google        b

    6   NAN         google        b
```

### Algorithm

1. I have a list of unique links/urls and I split it using `.` as a delimeter and assign this to `acronym`. As an example, `www.google.com` would convert into `google`.
2. Update dataframe acronym column where a unique link exists.
3. Find all unique addresses corresponding to the unique link and update the acronym with these addresses I found.

Now I think my code needs some optimization.

### Code

```
 for link in list_of_unique_links:
        if( len(link.split('.')) >1):
            acronym = link.split('.')[-2]
        else :
            acronym = link
        print(acronym)
        test_df.loc[test_df['links'] == link ,'acronyms'] =acronym
        #Get all associated address with this link and also add 
        for address in test_df[test_df['links'] == link  ].address.values:
            test_df.loc[test_df['address'] == address ,'acronyms'] =acronym
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to CodeReview. I did a simple editing pass for formatting and spelling, but this question still does not meet our standards. There is not enough code for this to be reviewable - the code sample you've shown is too small to understand the context of the program as a whole. Also, please describe what the purpose of the application is, and what you'd like to get out of a review.

Comment: Hey I am implementing rulebased entity resolution in python. So It is a chunk of code for building training dataset. I need to make a column from which  I can identify the address and link belongs to same entity.

Comment: I would like from community to review my logic and tell me If I can increase it performance

Comment: I cannot run this code. Please read/understand the rules for Code Review verses Stack Overflow.